# Send vector from R to Perl

Tags: r, perl

I'm stuck on passing data from R to Perl. I'm using the Statistics::R CPAN module.

test.R

`a <- c(1:10)`

test.pl

```
my $R=Statistics::R->new();
$R->run_from_file(q'test.R');
my $output = $R->get('a');
print "Variable a = $output\n";
```

This works fine if the variable in R is single value. However, I cannot pass a vector. I'm most likely missing a simple concept, but could not find any documentation or other questions here. The resulting text spits out, to me, nonsense. `Variable a = ARRAY(0x7fcbd9b26ff8)`

My ugly alternative is to have R write out a text file with the information, and have Perl read the parse the text back in. There must be a simpler way.

---

This is the simplified version. I'd like to send a list/vector of string values to Perl that will be variable based on user-input. My current project is set up so that Perl is the interface (I'm not the best with Perl) and R is dynamically interacting with the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like `$output` isn't an array, but is an array reference.

Try dereferencing it:

```
print @$output;
```

Or:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print $output;
```

Which will display the contents. You'll need to iterate the array to do anything constructive with it though:

```
print join ("\n", @$output ),"\n";
```

Comment: Howdy, thanks! I had to read up on dereferencing in Perl — declaring variables is tricker than I thought. Your answer was very straightforward, I appreciate it.